# css file defined in .info file is not loading in Drupal 7

Tags: theming

This is the my .info file details

```
name = Tripsinn
description = A flexible, recolorable theme with many regions.
package = Core
version = VERSION
core = 7.x
stylesheets[all][] = css/responsiveslides.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
scripts[] = js/responsiveslides.min.js
```

but these css are not loading

URL: http://dev.easysites.in/tripsinn/

this is a custom drupal theme under development.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I would suggest you to format the .info file code you posted. In this particular case, the position of the ends-of-line might be important.

Comment: Please remove package option from theme .info file, also remove semicolon from end of lines if any.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see in the URL you posted, both `css/style.css` and `js/responsiveslides.min.js` are being loaded fine, but there is no trace of the `css/responsiveslides.css` file. Maybe you are not placing that file in the appropriate directory?

Hope that helps,